# Paypal payment method

Tags: paypal

Which method is secured and best for Paypal Payments.

1.)

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=xxx@123.com&custom=XXXX&    return=XXXXXX&cancel=XXXXXX&notify_url=XXXX
```

2.)

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">  
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="221">  
<input type="image" name="submit" border="0"  
src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"  
alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">  
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1"  
src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >  
</form>
```

Thnx in Advance

Comment: So the question is basically `POST` vs. `GET`? Both methods are secure (as shown by the `https` protocol), and since it doesn't look like there's any sensitive data being sent as a parameter in either one (which would show up in the address bar and be saved in the history in the instance of `GET`), it's really just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.)
The post method is always the safe method.

Comment: actully i dont need to fill the form m getting details from database...what do u think?

Comment: are only making the payment by clicking a link?

Comment: The method you are using is called Website payment standard

Comment: you can use the 1 st method. In your case you are not storing any values, this will work. Use the second method if you have to store or retrieve any thing to database